# How to open .pdf, .doc files in Windows Phone (C#)

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any possibility to open word or pdf file in Windows Phone ?
I get the file byte data from specified API, and I want to have possibility in my application to preview the file...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use  [FOXIT SDK for WP7](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/sdk/embedded/)

Comment: not working for Window PHONE Apps, works just for Windows 8 Store Apps

Comment: @Joel: You need send request for Foxit corporation for Wp7 Foxit SDK

Answer (score 1):

you might have a look at this tutorial:

http://mobile.dzone.com/news/displaying-pdf-files-windows

But the component used is not open source. http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/PdfViewerPhone/

As far as i know there are no open source pdf viewer implementations for WP7/8 available.

You could try to get ComponentOne for **free** or with an massiv discount if you are an registered windows phone developer. Have a look at http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/featured/partners