# WinPhone accessing local file

Tags: windows-phone-8, win-phone-silverlight-8.1

In Windows Phone I have a PDF stored here:

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder / myfile.pdf
```

How can I open that PDF for viewing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141973/how-to-open-pdf-doc-files-in-windows-phone-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the LaunchFileAsync method of Launcher class. Example:

```
// Access the file.
StorageFile pdfFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("file.pdf");   
Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("file.pdf");
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdfFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `LaunchFileAsync`to open your `PDF`file?

[How to open pdf file in Windows Phone 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615504/)